# Redirect URL through Cron Job

Tags: linux, unix, cron, cpanel, schedule

I want to redirect some URLs on schedule basis. Let's say for example:

```
Redirect - http://example.com to http://google.com
Next day - http://example.com to http://bing.com
Next day - http://example.com to http://yahoo.com
..and so on
```

How this can be achieved through Cron Job?

Comment: Alter the /etc/hosts file? - this is not straightforward on all versions.  Systemd is different from Solaris for example.  Restart the  name service to flush the dns cache.  What exact OS do you have?

Comment: I'm using cPanel and the OS is Linux/Unix. Could you please explain in details? I'd appreciate.

Comment: the hosts file on a client can be used to avoid dns lookup, if you just want to redirect 1 client to a different website, use the host file of that client as suggested by jim. If you control example.com (the fact you mention cpanel suggests you control it) suggests this, the /etc/hosts/ file won't be of any help to you.

Comment: You want to change what the DNS entry points to (for everyone)? You want to change what looking that DNS entry up on your specific system returns? You want to change where people are redirected if they connect to that site with their browser (but always have them come to your site first)?

Comment: If you own example.com then you can just put a php script like this <?php header("Location: http://bing.com/"); ?> and then have cron replace the script or use an array to change based on date using a modulus or something.